# Add data to interface{} in struct

Tags: go, struct, interface

I want to add a data `{"foo2": "bar2"}` to `data` in struct `sample` at below `fmt.Println(s)` in `main()`.

### Script

```
type sample struct {
    data interface{}
}

func (s *sample) func1() {
    obj := map[string]interface{}{}
    obj["foo1"] = "bar1"
    s.data = obj
}

func main() {
    s := &sample{}
    s.func1()
    fmt.Println(s)

    // Above here is fixed as a condition of this question.
    // Here, I want to add {"foo2": "bar2"} to s.data

}
```

### My tests

I tried below.

#### Test 1:

```
s.data["foo2"] = "bar2"
```

Error occurs. It's `type interface {} does not support indexing`.

#### Test 2:

```
obj := map[string]interface{}{}
t, _ := json.Marshal(s.data)
json.Unmarshal(t, &obj)
obj["foo2"] = "bar2"
fmt.Println(obj)
```

There are no errors. `{"foo2": "bar2"}` can be added.

Is this 2nd test effective or general method? If there are how to directly add data or other methods, will you please teach me.
Thank you so much for your time. And I'm sorry for my immature question.

Comment: This is not working. A `map[string]interface{}` implements the empty interface but you want to use a empty interface as a map. That way it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for what reason you want to have an empty interface type instead of the map[string]interface{} type, but it can be done.

```
type sample struct {
    data interface{}
}

func (s *sample) func1() {
    obj := map[string]interface{}{}
    obj["foo1"] = "bar1"
    s.data = obj
}

func (s *sample) addField(key, value string) {
    v, _ := s.data.(map[string]interface{})
    v[key] = value
    s.data = v
}

func main() {
    s := &sample{}
    s.func1()
    fmt.Println(s)

    s.addField("foo2", "bar2")
    fmt.Println(s)

}
```

You have to cast the interface into a map[string]interface{} each time you want to add a value. This can also be done to retrieve a value, I'm sure you can add another method using what I provided to do that.

I would advise against doing this. Either you'll always have a map[string]interface{}, so you should make that the type of data, or you'll have to be careful as there is no guarantee that you have a map[string]interface{} so you'll have to handle this accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I could get a solution for me. And I'm sorry for my poor skill.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the definition of your struct to:

```
type sample struct {
    data map[string]interface{}
}
```

it should work.

So why? Because you are defining data as `interface{}`. But you this is not a map it is an empty interface. Why it is not a map? Because it could be also an int, string or another struct. So you can not use that type like other types.

In your examples you are using `data` always as a map, so the solution would be to define data as the type `map[string]interface{}`

Comment: Thank you for your advices. But I'm sorry. I know when uses ``data map[string]interface{}``, ``s.data["foo2"] = "bar2"`` can be used. My question is looking for how to solve for below ``// Here, I want to add {"foo2": "bar2"} to s.data``. So ``data interface{}`` is also a condition. I'm sorry for my poor explanation.